# Getting a signed angle value

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm having an issue with finding an angle between two vectors. I have this code (pic below) in blueprints, which uses dot product in order to find cos of the angle between two vectors.

[image]

However, it seems that this method does not give me full information - I still cannot determine if the object, which position I am tracking, is left or right from me. I believe it is because cos is
even function and does not provide information about angle's sign.

Is there any way to determine angle's signed value? May be some C++ magic? I would really appreciate some help in this case.

Comment: The dot product has this information for you. If it's negative it on the left, if positive the object is on your right. (Or perhaps exatly the opposite, you have to try it)

Comment: I don't think that's right.   To get the left/right information, look at the sign of the cross product   (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot product will only give you the cosine of the angle formed by the two vectors. It is positive of they are facing the same direction, negative for opposite directions and 0 if they are perpendicular.

Simply check the "RightDirection" to get the sign that corresponds to the original dot product.

By doing this, you will exclude the zeros given by the cardinal directions, so substitute the opposite axis when zero.

Here is the Blueprint pseudocode:

```
   Vector TargetDirection = Normalize(Player.GetActorLocation - Object.GetActorLocation);
   float LR = dot(TargetDirection, Player.GetActorRotation.GetRightVector);
   float SignLR = Sign(LR); // returns -1,0,1
   float Angle = dot(TargetDirection,Player.GetActorRotation.GetForwardVector);

// catch the dot product zeros at(0,90,180,270...) 
// if is a float comparison object with the bool output passed to a branch

   if(Angle == 0) Angle = LR; // pick a direction (90 degrees left or right)
   if(SignLR == 0) SignLR = Angle; //pick a direction


   float Signed Angle = SignLR * Angle;
```

Note: The variables are not needed, when implementing this code, the output pin is wired directly to the multiple inputs.

Comment: I thought about the question some more and realized that since asker already has a rotator involved, using the GetRightVector  and dot for the sign saves on computation overall, and your answer took that approach first, so I'm upvoting this answer just for being that helpful. One big improvement that would help it further would be to make `Angle` an angle that asker could use by using `Acos` (radians), `DegAcos` (degrees) or equivalent calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has a good solution for your specific use case since you can use the rotator to find the actor's local right direction quickly. More generally (such as if a rotator is not involved), if you need to get the angle and its relative direction from the perspective of some arbitrary up axis you can use this function:

```cpp
// Header
UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure)
static void AngleAndDirection(const struct FVector& FromNormalized, 
        const struct FVector& ToNormalized, 
        const struct FVector& UpAxisNormalized, 
        float& OutAngle, float& OutDirection);

// Source
void UClassName::AngleAndDirection(const FVector& FromNormalized, 
        const FVector& ToNormalized, const FVector& UpAxisNormalized, 
        float& OutAngle, float& OutDirection)
{
    OutAngle = UKismetMathLibrary::Acos(
            FVector::DotProduct(FromNormalized, ToNormalized));
    FVector Right = FVector::CrossProduct(UpAxisNormalized, FromNormalized);
    float Dot = FVector::DotProduct(UpAxisNormalized, Right);
    OutDirection = UKismetMathLibrary::SignOfFloat(Dot);
}
```

Where:

- `FromNormalized` and `ToNormalized`, and `UpAxisNormalized` are (of course) normalized
- `OutDirection` is positive if  `ToNormalized` is on the relative rightwards, negative if leftwards, or zero if neither (could be in front, above, below, or directly behind)
- `OutAngle` is measured in radians.

If you need degrees, you can use `DegACos` instead of `Acos`.

This function could be put into a [Blueprint Function Library](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/BlueprintFunctionLibraries/) if you are using one, so you could use it with your blueprints.

Comment: ah, yes I'm used to how sign works in unity where sign(0) := 1, and also forgot to include normalization at the top. Will fix momentarily. once i fix this then dotproduct(axis, cross) will be 0 when axis is coplanar with origin, from, and to (in which case neither direction is "more" correct), when axis is zero (which i would consider an input with an unspecified output), or if from and to are colinear (another case where neither direction is more correct)

Comment: Yes, ambiguity abounds(pick a direction.) I am also struggling with Z inversion of a single actor? Not sure whether or not to flip the X,Y axes.  Z alone would require another term in my solution. No matter the differences in origin space,  our solutions are linearly connected.

Comment: If  `from` and `to` are both normalized, does that give the Dot product = Acos?
Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Strom `cos(θ) = â ⋅ b̂` so why not do both?